# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field in Django - ForeignKey Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Please check me this error with serializers.
I have a model Avatar:

```
class Avatar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='avatar_user', null=True)
    photoset = models.ForeignKey(PhotoSet, null=True, blank=True)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=avatar_file_path)
```

I created a serializer User with avatar

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BasicAvatarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Avatar
        fields = [
            'user',
            'photoset',
            'image',
        ]

class UserBasicSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    avatar_set = BasicAvatarSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'avatar_set',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        ]
```

But it get error:

```
AttributeError at /api/v1/users/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `avatar_set` on serializer `UserBasicSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'avatar_set'.
```

[view error by photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXBnF.png)

Comment: please post the exact error message.

Comment: and add the User model too, error is about this model apparently

Comment: @rollinger I updated it, bro

Comment: @PRMoureu i use the default User model

Answer (score 1):

I success full fix it by use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BasicAvatarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Avatar
        fields = [
            'user',
            'photoset',
            'image',
        ]

class UserBasicSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    avatar_user = BasicAvatarSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'avatar_user',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        ]
```

Change avatar_set to avatar_user because **related_name='avatar_user'** in User. Thank you @PRMoureu and @rollinger!